# Android Login and Registration with PHP, MySQL and SQLite

Tags: php, eclipse

The application is getting forcibly closed and showing this erros in log file:

```
03-04 10:52:38.694: E/AndroidRuntime(1095): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 10:52:38.694: E/AndroidRuntime(1095): Process: com.example.androidhive, PID: 1095
03-04 10:52:38.694: E/AndroidRuntime(1095): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 10:52:38.694: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at com.example.androidhive.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:65)
03-04 10:52:38.694: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
03-04 10:52:38.694: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
03-04 10:52:38.694: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-04 10:52:38.694: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-04 10:52:38.694: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-04 10:52:38.694: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
03-04 10:52:38.694: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 10:52:38.694: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-04 10:52:38.694: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
03-04 10:52:38.694: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
03-04 10:52:38.694: E/AndroidRuntime(1095):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Why am I getting this error ?

Comment: This doesn't look like a PHP issue at all; looks to be an issue with the underlying Android Java code.

Comment: hey ChrisForrence thanks for helping but the issue was in php file only i had created a wrong query i jst fixed it and its working grt.....